# QSyntaxHighlighter not working for form created QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

As the title suggests, highlighting doesn't seem to work with form created QTextEdit.
My QSyntaxHighlighter derrivate class is the one from [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq21-syntaxhighlighter.html#example) and my code (the one that doesn't work):

```
ui->setupUi(this);
HtmlHighlighter hl(ui->textEdit->document());
```

but if I do this it works fine:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow win;
    win.show();
    QTextEdit editor;
    HighLighter highlighter(editor.document());
    editor.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Is there any way to get it to work with the form generated one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your highlighter is going out of scope at the end of the constructor.  Put it on the heap and make it a member variable, and it should work.

```
class MainWindow
{
//...

private:
    HtmlHighlighter * h1;
}
```

Then in your cpp file:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
hl = new HtmlHighlighter(ui->textEdit->document());
```

Hope that helps.